# Step by step contract debugging

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging

This question is related to [these](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7686/faster-deployment-of-contracts-using-geth/7689) [questions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/184/how-can-i-debug-a-smart-contract).

Is there any tool that allows for step-by-step contract debugging? I have tried using mix but it really is broken at this point: contracts don't get deployed, transactions are never mined, etc.

**Edit:**

The duplicate is about testing functions not debugging them step-by-step.

Comment: Not a duplicate I want to step into the function, not test it against an output.

Comment: Something like `pry` for ruby? Or `locas` for node?

Comment: Yes, anything that allows "walking" through the code and examining the state of variables, return values, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Mix IDE that is being phased out.

There will be a new tool called [Remix IDE](https://github.com/ethereum/remix). Currently it does VM level stepping and source level stepping is coming.

Comment: I've tried it. It's currently a work in progress. I'm giving `truffle` a try.