# Setting up a truffle project

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, truffle

I'm reading truffles's [docs](http://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/build/) and am trying to build a custom project with a contract and a few test cases (written in a js file). I need to do this because **testrpc** is (considerably) faster than **geth**. My setup is as follows:

I have a directory for the project with the following layout:

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 user user 4096 Aug  4 10:55 app
drwxr-xr-x 4 user user 4096 Aug  4 11:35 build
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Aug  4 11:06 contracts
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Aug  4 10:55 migrations
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Aug  4 11:24 test
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  248 Aug  4 10:55 truffle.js
```

The files were created using `truffle init`. I've cleared the contracts in the `contracts` directory and the js files in the `test` directory.

I have a contract:

**C.sol**

```
contract C {

    string words = "Bla bla bla";

    uint256 lastVal;

    function math(uint256 a, uint256 b) returns (uint256) {
        lastVal = a + b;
        return lastVal;
    }

    function getWords() constant returns (string) {
        return words;
    }
}
```

in the `contracts` directory and a test file:

**c.js**

```
contract('C', function(accounts) {
  it("Getting the words string from the contract", function() {
    var c = C.deployed();

    return c.getWords.call(accounts[0]).then(function(words) {
      assert.equal(words, "Bla bla bla", "[E] The contract should have said \"Bla bla bla\"");
    });
  });

  it(" 2 + 2 = 4 ", function(){
    var c = C.deployed();

    return c.math(2, 2).then(function(additionResult){
        assert.equal(additionResult, 4, "[E] 2 + 2 = 4 even in eth. contracts.");
    });
  });
});
```

in the `tests` directory. I have manually cleared the `build` directory and ran

```
truffle build
```

int the base directory. Nothing (no artifacts) gets built in the `build` directory. Why?

Does anybody have a minimal setup that does not involve developing a web app? only the contract **.sol** files and js test files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is not in the build directory but in the `./environments/` directories.

Truffle knows 4 environments by default

- development
- staging
- production
- test

Each environment is configurable to use a different blockchain.
You can change your environment by `truffle deploy -e <environment>`

Read more on the configuration in the [truffle docs](http://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/docs/advanced/environments/).

Comment: Now I ran into another issue related to testing methods. I've opened a ticket here: https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle/issues/225 . I have no environments directories in my project directory.

Comment: In version v2.0.4 that I'm using `truffle init` doesn't create the environment directories anymore.

Comment: Do you have a minimal setup of truffle? I'm stuck at testing state changing methods: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7822/minimal-contract-testing-setup-using-truffle