# Minimal contract testing setup using truffle

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging, truffle

This question is a follow up onto [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7775/testing-contracts-with-truffle) one. I have tried following the suggestion in the answer of adding a `done()` method that fires when an error occurs (an exception is raised) but it doesn't when I test the code.

Does anybody have a minimal setup that can test state changing contract method calls? (in my example, the `call()` method that read the blockchain works fine (an error is thrown if the expected strange and it passes if not)).

Comment: Maybe this test could help you https://github.com/vincentlg/projectforreproduce/blob/master/test/crowdFunding.js